# Short story about an uploaded consciousness running traffic signals

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

This story would have originally appeared in either *Analog* or *Asimov's* in the late 1980s to early 1990s.

The viewpoint character is a human being whose uploaded consciousness has to work a number of unpleasant jobs (one of which is running the traffic signals in an intersection) to earn money needed for its own upkeep. The story ends, if I remember correctly, on an optimistic note, with them being sent into space.

Searching online hasn't yielded anything that seems relevant.

Comment: It's a novel rather than a shirt story, but the premise reminds me of "We are legion (we are Bob)"